# Change form using Jade/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to get a form to change its options in response to another event. Cakes needs to update when .sweet is changed, but cakes is originally passed though res.render and I dont know how to change it without reloading the page. I just the best ajax solution to this.

**app:**

```
res.render('index', {cakes: json_object});
```

**body:**

```
form(name="myform")
    div.input
        each item in cakes.topping
            input(type="checkbox", name=item.color)
            | #{item.color}
```

Trying to change cakes:

**head:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //requesting new Object
    $(".sweet").change(function () {
        socket.emit('choose', {sweet: $("#cho_swe").val()});
    });

    //getting new object
    socket.on('set_sweet', function(object){
         -- object is a new JSON which needs to replace cakes in the form below
    });

});
```

How do I get my new object into a format I can use in my loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**note: will refer to jade as pug to honor their forced brand change.**

Pug compiles on the backend when you render them inside your app file. However, you're sending additional variables in parallel with your rendered file which pug has no scope over.

When you render it, you lose access to Pug functions

each

```
item in cakes.topping
```

is now

```
<input 1/>
<input 2/>
etc...
```

At this point, Pug's finished it's job and now it's a front end issue. You can't use pug's loop function, you'll need to rely on a front end framework or library to make the content dynamic.

There are a few ways to handle this but I see you're using jquery so we can just go that route:

Repopulate the element when the socket broadcast is received:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //get the form element
    $form = $('form[name="myform"]').empty();

    //requesting new Object
    $(".sweet").change(function () {
        socket.emit('choose', {sweet: $("#cho_swe").val()});
    });

    //getting new object
    socket.on('set_sweet', function(object){
    //
    // clear the current form and add the new html
    // if you know most of the html before hand and just have a few dynamic
    // fields consider having them in the pug template with 
    // display: none;
    //
        // dynamically add new elements without needing a page reload
        object.forEach(function(val, key) {
            $form.append('<div>'
                   +' <input type="checkbox" onclick="someClickHandler()" name="' + val + '"/>'
                   +' <div>' + val + '</div>'
                   +' </div>');
        });
    });
});
```

If you find yourself needing to do a lot of dynamic content, consider pairing  up with a framework like angularjs.

A solution to the above with angular would be akin to:

```
form(name="myform")
    div.input
        div(ng-repeat="item in items")
            input(type="checkbox", name=item.color)
            | #{item.color}

socket.on('set_sweet', function(object){
     $scope.items = object;
});
```

To sum it up, pug is going to compile a page on the backend with everything available to it, variables and all, but as soon as it's passed off and rendered, it's your job on the front end to make the content dynamic.